# How do I pass a token as a constructor parameter for a Crowdsale contract

Tags: ico, crowdsale, openzeppelin

I am trying to modify the [OpenZeppelin Crowdsale.sol contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol) for my own purpose and in the constructor it takes a token.

```
  function Crowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet, MintableToken _token) public {
```

What do I need to do there? When I try passing in the name of the token contract that I am attempting to crowdsale I get

```
creation of Crowdsale errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 46
```

I am using remix.

I am very confused as I cannot find any examples of how this contract is actually implemented anywhere. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually syntax errors involving JSON means you're not entering the contract arguments correctly.

Are you entering the address in double quotes? For example: `"0xbbf289d846208c16edc8474705c748aff07732db"`

I think this particular example requires you to create a token contract separately and then pass in the address of that token when initializing your crowdsale contract.

Answer (score 0):

You just pass the address of the token to it.

Comment: Does this mean I cannot have the Crowdsale contract inheriting from the Token contract (because that would mean calling a new constructor for a Token contract which would create an entirely new Token with a different address?). 

I appreciate your help. I am new to solidity and the documentation regarding inheritance and constructors is quite dense, and does not seem geared towards ICO contract development.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to do that it says " The constructor should be payable if you send value debug the transaction if you get more information" . What does it mean?